# Running vmdk files from NAS with ESXi 5.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, vmdk

I have a ESXi 5.1 Server and a 12TB Thecus n4200eco(~5.5TB in RAID6). I want to be able to run the virtual machines from the NAS instead of the server because the server has no RAID and I don't trust the drives in there.

Is this possible? Or is it a bad idea? And how do I achieve this if it is?

Answer (score 1):

If the NAS supports NFS or iSCSI then you can certainly use it as a datastore for vSphere.

Depending on which it supports and which you want to use, the setup is slightly different. Which does it support and which do you want to use?

Comment: It appears that it supports both - is one better than the other for this use?

Comment: They each have their use cases. Personally I would use iSCSI.